# message from debugger:terminated due to memory pressure IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

in server side data i am getting 17000 users names.when i get 1000 user names ofter Xcode is crashing giving these error **message from debugger:terminated due to memory pressure** please help me how to get 17000 user names data how to handle without memory presser.i got these problem in real device.

why i am taking array in app delegate i need to use these 17000 user names in so many view controllers

```
I am declare array
AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *userNamesGettingArrayObj;

I am declare string
ModelClass.h
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *nameString;

ModelClass.m
// i am getting server data in these dictionary object
NSDictionary *dictobj=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
        for (int i = 0; i<=[[dictobj valueForKey:@"name"] count]-1;i++)
        {
            _nameString=[[dictobj valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:i];
            [delegate.userNamesGettingArrayObj addObject:_nameString];
        }


viewController.m

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [delegate.userNamesGettingArrayObj count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (_tableViewObj == tableView) {
        static NSString *ide=@"ide";
        UITableViewCell *cell=[_tableViewObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ide];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ide];
        }

            cell.textLabel.text=[delegate.userNamesGettingArrayObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont get that much data from sever at same time, use load more button or auto hit functions when your table reach at end of list.

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;{
      if(nearByPlacesTableView.contentOffset.y >= (nearByPlacesTableView.contentSize.height - nearByPlacesTableView.bounds.size.height)) {
        if (isPageRefresing) {
           // [self performSelector:@selector(getRecords:) withObject:nextPageTokenString afterDelay:0.0f];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getRecords:) withObject:nextPageTokenString];
      }
   }
 }
```

// HTTP Utility class
    -(void)getRecords:(NSString *)token{

```
NSString *serverUrl;


if ([self.headStr isEqualToString:@"Nearby"])
{
    serverUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=%@&key=AIzaSyCd2",token];
}else{
    serverUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken=%@&key=AIzaSyCd2",token];
}

//Create URL and Request
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverUrl];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse * response;
NSError * error = nil;
//Send Request
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error == nil)
{
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *nextpageArr = [NSMutableArray new];
    nextpageArr = [[json valueForKey:@"results"] mutableCopy];
    nextPageTokenString=[json valueForKey:@"next_page_token"];

    for (id dict in  [json valueForKey:@"results"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;
        if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            mutableDict=[dict mutableCopy];
        }
        else{
            mutableDict=dict;
        }
        [mutableDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"checked"];
        [mutableDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"is_favourite"];
        [nextpageArr addObject:mutableDict];
    }

    NSString *status=[json valueForKey:@"status"];
    if ([status isEqualToString:@"INVALID_REQUEST"]) {
        isPageRefresing=NO;
    }else if ([status isEqualToString:@"OK"]){
        isPageRefresing=YES;
    }
    if (nextpageArr.count) {
        [self.nearbyVenues addObjectsFromArray:nextpageArr];
    }

    [nearByPlacesTableView reloadData];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet" message:@"Please check your internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
  }
 }
```

Comment: hi,is it possible or not to get all the data at a time and store into array

Comment: No, it is not possible to store that mch data in array, either you have to store it in core data by fetching records in loop, or have an option like load more

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your repeated repeated repeated use of valueForKey may be the problem. Whether it is the problem or not, it is so inefficient it hurts my eyes. About 100 times faster:

```
NSArray* names = dictObj [@"name"];
NSMutableArray* userNames = delegate.userNamesGettingArrayObj;

for (NSString* nameString in names)
    [names addObject:nameString];
```

17,000 names should be no problem whatsoever unless there's something wrong with your code.

valueForKey is a high-level method that is usually entirely inappropriate for processing JSON, or for accessing anything stored in a dictionary. Unless you have a very good reason (one that you could explain if asked about it), use objectForKey or just [@"someKey"].

Comment: hi,finally solve my problem its really help your code thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried??

make response dict golable and
cell.textlable.text=[dictobj valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

Comment: hi ,these idea also help me to reach my problem,finally solve my problem its really help your code thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

//i store all data into at time when i am using these code

```
delegate.userNamesGettingArrayObj=[[[NSArray arrayWithObject:dictobj]valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
```